# How to convert TypeScript to JavaScript in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter, material-ui

I am still new to learning `React` and I am having a tough time changing from `TypeScript` to `JavaScript`

In the below code table filter is used with `TypeScript`. How can I convert the code to `JavaScript`?

[Code link of codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-table-search-demo-x3viu)

Comment: Converting from Typescript to Javascript, seems an odd thing to do, especially if your having issues learning React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted **tsx to js** .It's working for me . Here is a code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";



const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 650
  }
});

const  food = [
  { name: "Pizza", calories: 200, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0 },
  { name: "Hot Dog", calories: 300, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0 },
  { name: "Burger", calories: 400, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0 },
  { name: "Hamburger", calories: 500, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0 },
  { name: "Fries", calories: 600, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0 },
  { name: "Ice Cream", calories: 700, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0 }
];

export default function SampleDesignsImage() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(food);
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState("");
  const classes = useStyles();

  const requestSearch = (searchedVal) => {
    const filteredRows = food.filter((row) => {
      return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase());
    });
    setRows(filteredRows);
  };

  const cancelSearch = () => {
    setSearched("");
    requestSearch(searched);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Paper>
        <SearchBar
          value={searched}
          onChange={(searchVal) => requestSearch(searchVal)}
          onCancelSearch={() => cancelSearch()}
        />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Food (100g serving)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.name}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
      <br />
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="https://smartdevpreneur.com/the-easiest-way-to-implement-material-ui-table-search/"
      >
        Learn how to add search and filter to Material-UI Table here.
      </a>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can build the code using the `tsc` script and you'll have a `dist` directory which contains the JS files